# 404 when call Dajaxice function cause of WSGI Alias

Tags: python, django, wsgi, dajaxice, dajax

I have comboboxes into a form that refresh dynamically with Dajaxice, I have no problems in development for do this but in production with WSGI I have the follow problem:

VirtualHost for project has an alias `WSGIScriptAlias /dgp /path/to/wsgi` for load the web application, all routes construct under this subsite but Dajaxice don't, where the url has to be `http://example.com/dgp/dajaxice/ventas.updatecomboproducto/` instead that we have `http://example.com/dajaxice/ventas.updatecomboproducto/` where obviously can't find anything so I don't know how to tell Dajaxice notices the wsgi alias, I tried with `DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX='dgp'` but that only works under the subsite, that means, only works with `http://desarrollorivas.no-ip.org/dgp/dgp/dajaxice/ventas.updatecomboproducto/` that's not resolve anything.

Any ideas? That's the code, in `categoria` is where I invoke the Dajaxice process and load the url:

```
class DetallePedidoModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    categoria = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[0, '----------']] + [[c.id, c.nombre] for c  in Categoria.objects.all()],widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'onchange': 'Dajaxice.ventas.updatecomboproducto(Dajax.process, {"option":this.value,"id":this.id});'}))
    #producto = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[0, '----------']] + [[p.id, p.nombre] for p  in Producto.objects.all()],widget=forms.Select(
        #attrs={'onchange': 'Dajaxice.ventas.updatevaluecantidadproducto(Dajax.process, {"option":this.value,"id_producto":this.id});'}))
    cantidad = forms.IntegerField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'min':'0','step':'1','style':'width: 50px;','value':'0'}))
    descuento =  forms.FloatField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'step':'any','style':'width: 50px;','value':'0.0'}))
    pvp_manipulacion =  forms.FloatField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'step':'any','value':'0.0'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Detalle_Pedido
        fields = ["id","categoria","producto","unidad_precio","cantidad","descuento","manipulacion","pvp_manipulacion"]

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(DetallePedidoModelForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['categoria'].empty_label = "Selecciona una categoria"
        self.fields['producto'].widget.attrs["onchange"] = 'Dajaxice.ventas.updatevaluecantidadproducto(Dajax.process, {"option":this.value,"id_producto":this.id});'




PedidoForm = modelform_factory(Pedido, PedidoModelForm, exclude=("producto",),formfield_callback=make_custom_datefield)
DetallePedidoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Detalle_Pedido,exclude=("unidad_precio","pedido",),
                                            form=DetallePedidoModelForm)
```

**urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 from django.contrib import admin
 from . import views
 from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
 dajaxice_autodiscover()

 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'dgp.views.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^login/$', views.login,{'template_name': 'login.html'},name="my_login"),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name': 'login.html'},name="my_login"),
    url(r'^logout/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',{'template_name': 'logout.html'},name="my_logout"),
    url(r'^ventas/', include('ventas.urls', namespace="ventas")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('ventas.urls')),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
    )+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be taking into consideration that the URL mount point of the application may not be at the root of the web site by using the appropriate functions to construct a URL which includes the mount point. See the documentation at:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/

Comment: And how could be for Dajaxice? All I have is an url pattern like this `url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),` and the rest of urls only point at 'root' of `dgp`, why Dajaxice not interpretate the same as the others? I'm going to edit with the urls.py for you can see that what I'm trying to say, using `reverse`not help in this case because I'm using a Dajax function which I pass the process with a few args, I think I'm missing something...